# Accessing property of COM wrapper object created in another thread while COM still running

Tags: c#, com, geckofx

Hi I am using GeckoFX (COM wrapper of Firefox webcontrol). I am creating the browser like below:

```
public ScrapperGecko() // constructor
{
    ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(CreateBrowser);
    CreateThread = new Thread(ts);
    CreateThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    CreateThread.Start();
}

public void CreateBrowser()
{
    if (_Browser != null) return;
    Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "xulrunner"));

    _Browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();

    _Browser.DocumentCompleted += _Browser_DocumentCompleted;
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    _Browser.Height = frm.ClientSize.Height;
    _Browser.Width = frm.ClientSize.Width;
    _Browser.Left = 0;
    _Browser.Top = 0;
    _Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    frm.ShowInTaskbar = true;
    frm.Controls.Add(_Browser);
    frm.Show();
}
```

However when I call the ScrapperGecko's method that accesses the Gecko from another thread like below:

```
public string GetCookie()
{
    if (_Browser == null || _Browser.Document == null || _Browser.Document.DocumentElement == null) //Throw exception
        return string.Empty;
    return _Browser.Document.Cookie;
}
```

Whenever it hits _Browser.Document it throws an exception.

> An exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException' occurred in
>   Geckofx-Winforms.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: COM object that has been separated from its
>   underlying RCW cannot be used.

After that, I try to modify the method becomes like this (using InvokeRequire), but after then it always return null, is the InvokeRequire approach correct, and why does the return value is null which it supposes to contain cookies?

```
public string GetCookie()
{
    WaitForBrowser();
    if (_Browser.InvokeRequired)
    {
        object obj = _Browser.Invoke(new Func<string>(GetCookie), null); // it works but the obj always **null** which it suppose to have value
        return (string)obj;
    }

    if (_Browser == null || _Browser.Document == null || _Browser.Document.DocumentElement == null)
        return string.Empty;
    return _Browser.Document.Cookie;
}
```

The COM is still running and not yet released, because I set the COM object to be static, and never call Dispose on my own, I can be sure that the COM is still running, so it shouldn't be related to another question about the COM getting released and RCW error.

Comment: Hi it might not related to that question, because that question is about COM getting released, but mine the COM is still running and its not yet closed.

Comment: So, when `GetCookie` is called through `_Browser.Invoke`, which of the properties in the `if` statement causes it to return `string.Empty`?

Comment: HI Alex, it return null not string.Empty. But the cookie has been set before the call which by right it should have value

Comment: Does `WaitForBrowser()` also need to be marshalled to the STA thread that ceated the `_Browser` instance, i.e. moved to below the `if (_browser.InvokeRequired)` block ?

Comment: Hi Alex, no WaitForBrowser only contains "while (IsBrowserReady == false) Application.DoEvents();" while IsBrowserReady will be true After the CreateBrowser() call (I omit that part earlier). Now again I try to call other function such as GetInnerHtml which has InvokeRequired similar as GetCookie but rather than returning Document.Cookie it returns Document.DocumentElement.InnerHtml, and again it is null which I am pretty sure that it has value This is very weird.

Comment: Your code suffers from a threading race bug, one of the fundamental bugs when you write threaded code.  Your 2nd version is a bit better, but still not nearly good enough.  The browser's ready signal does *not* mean that the cookie is valid.  You must do this the correct way, use the DocumentCompleted event, obtain the cookie and *then* start the thread.  No risk of a race that way.